# best method to require passwords for some pages in a web site

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a site with most material publicly available but about 10% should be password protected. The site is published using NGINX on a Debian system.

What is the best approach to protect the few directories and single pages with a password (or some other form of authentication) ?

I think that NGINX would allow me to protect some directories, but this seems coarse and I am not sure if just ordering and listing all the directories to protect in the site configuration is a good idea.

I am obviously not an expert on NGINX configuration and thus my suspicion that there is a better way?

I have tried to use the advice given, but do not succeed. I have now:

```
map $uri $realm {
        /Reserved       "Username and Password required";
        default                 off;
}

server {
    server_name a.b.c;

    root /var/www/html/homepage;

    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location /homepage {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

     access_log /var/log/nginx/heiden.log;
...
}
```

What must go into the map, when the URI is `a.b.c/Reserved/index.html` and all other files in `Reserved/*` should be protected?  I have tried `a.b.c/Reserved/*` but it did not trigger the password request (or is the firefox saved passwords playing tricks with me?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way except the list of URI's you need to protect. Here is the example to protect them using the basic auth and the [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block with the list of URIs to protect:

```
map $uri $realm {
    /uri/to/protect/1    "Protected area";
    /uri/to/protect/2    "Protected area";
    ...
    default              off;
}
server {
    ...
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    ...
}
```

You can also use PRCE (or PCRE2 for nginx 1.21.5 or later) regex patterns inside the `map` block using the `~` (for case-sensitive matching) or `~*` (for case-insensitive matching) string prefix if your list can be somehow simplified that way. For example, to protect every URI starting with `/path/to/protected/area` you can use the following `map` block:

```
map $uri $realm {
    # every URI starting with the following prefix will require basic authorization
    ~^/path/to/protected/area  "Protected area";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful example, which is a bit better than what I though to do - but it remains  unfortunate that there is not better solution.

Comment: I tried the solution you propose, but did not achieve the protection. I included my attempts in the question. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: You should use PCRE/PCRE2 regex expressions. Domain name or HTTP access scheme (http/https) are not parts of the URI. Use `~^/Reserved/` (or `~*^/reserved/` for case insensitive comparsion) regex pattern.

Comment: thank you - now it works. Do you want to update your answer, so i can mark it as accepted. I think i would be important to say that wildcards are only possible iwth regex.

Comment: @user855443 I thought it was quite obvious from the original answer, but if it isn't, I added some clarifications (see the answer edit history).