# How to protect different parts of a site with differen password-sets (using NGINX)

Tags: nginx

I have been understanding, with the help of stackoverflow,  how to achieve password protection for a part of a NGINX served site - [see][1]. I tried to figure out from the NGINX doc if and how I could require different passwords (from different `.htpasswd` files) for different parts of the site. For example one set of passwords would allow users to see a `reserved` part and others a `private` part. Is this possible and what is the simplest form to achieve it?

I tried naively to add a password file in the `map`, but this fails when nginx is started.

```
map $uri $realm {
    ~^/Reserved/  "Protected area" /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    ~^/private/  "Private area" /etc/nginx/.htpasswd1;
}

server {
    server_name a.b.c;

    root /var/www/html/homepage;
    auth_basic $realm;
#    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

...
}
```

Can this configuration be fixed?

Perhaps [Vouch](https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy) would be a solution; if possible, I would love to avoid the additional complexity.

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154245/best-method-to-require-passwords-for-some-pages-in-a-web-site
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, surprisingly, straight forward: NGINX permits to have multiple location directives for a a single server. For each location directive a separate set of passwords can be set.

A reduced example NGINX `cfg` file for a server in sites enabled could be:

```
server {     

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name localhost;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /bakedHomepage {
        root /home/frank/Web ; 
        auth_basic "Username and Password required (Web)";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswdWeb;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /bakedHomepage/Reserved {
        root /home/frank/Web/ ; 
        auth_basic "Username and Password required (Reserved part of Web)";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswdReserved;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

     access_log /var/log/nginx/bhutan.log;
}
```

Files in `Web/Reserved` are protected by the passwords in `.htpasswdReserved` and the other files in `Web/` by the passwords in `.htpasswdWeb` - which may include different users with different passwords.